# C++ Builder debugger creates too many threads

Tags: multithreading, debugging, c++builder, ansi-c, debug-mode

What I got:

- Server console 32bit application written in ANSI C (free [open-source](https://github.com/igroglaz/Tangaria) multiplayer game);
- Application runs in Embarcadero C++ Builder 10.3 in '[Debug mode](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/699917093717671946/923662503551070208/unknown.png)';
- Server OS: Windows Server 2012 R2 64bit.

Sometimes there appears CPU load problem. Video demonstration of this problem: https://youtu.be/eyASiAUG2vI
(description of the video: I've paused IDE and went step-by-step with F7... then it become 'Process is not acessible' so I paused it again and went with F7 one more time).

It looks like a problem with the debugger. It creates too many threads for whatever reason and that clogs the CPU... Windows not able to create thread because it's in Windows kernel method "base threadinitthunk". "thread exit, thread start, thread exit..." and so on so the debugger creates so many threads Windows cannot deal with it. There is no multithread in the application except the debugger.

I've checked C++ Builder project options (screenshots: [1](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/699917093717671946/923669451734413312/unknown.png),[2](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/699917093717671946/923669503303356436/unknown.png),[3](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/699917093717671946/923669566192758804/unknown.png)) and can't find there options for thread loader. I wonder, is there a setting for C++ Builder to limit number of threads? Or some other workarounds?

Thanks!

Comment: So, how does it run without the debugger?

Comment: @TomBrunberg it runs alright I suppose. But the task is to run application with debugger all the time to perform tests.

Comment: AFAIK, the debugger doesn't create its own threads, it operates in the context of the application's threads, or in the IDE's main thread.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks! Apparently it was bug in the code. It's already fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was bug in the code. It's already fixed :) So debugger was innocent after all...